# Alternatives for ArcGIS API for .Net

Tags: api, .net, gis, tiff

I want to choose GIS API to show TIFF maps (and also possibly MapInfo and OpenStreeMap maps) in my .Net application. What alternatives to ArcGIS .Net API can I use? Free if possible.

Comment: What features are you looking for?

Comment: I would like to have an ability to display maps of this types(Tiff, MapInfo, OSM), drawing of geometric figures on the map and ability to add pictures to the map.